# Creating the ECharts animated bar chart in Angular 16?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

The ECharts animated bar chart works fine on Stackblitz.  [This is the Stackblitz Angular 16 demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qph6ya?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fecharts.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

When I try the same demo in a local Angular 16 project, it produces the following errors.

```
Error: src/app/animated-echarts.component.ts:21:55 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'autoResize' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

21       '<div echarts (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)" [autoResize]="false" [options]="options"></div>',
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/animated-echarts.component.ts:21:76 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

21       '<div echarts (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)" [autoResize]="false" [options]="options"></div>',
```

[This is the local version on Github](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/charts).  To see the error:

```
git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/charts.git
cd charts
npm i
ng serve -o
```

Thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/issues/399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the Angular CLI created a version 15 project, and so the right `ngx-echarts` for that is version `15.03`.

In order to fix it I updated the Angular CLI.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

And recreated the project as an Angular 16 project, and now it works.